# How do I use centralManager willRestoreState in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I'm having my app use its phone as a central and carry out a task when its peripheral broadcasts. As such I'm struggling with

```
func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, willRestoreState dict: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {

}
```

The CoreBluetooth Programming Guide is quite vague as to what goes in this function and all the examples I see are in Objective-C which I don't know very well. For example:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central willRestoreState:(NSDictionary *)state {
    activePeripheral = [state[CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey] firstItem];
    activePeripheral.delegate = self;

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %lu", @"Device: ", activePeripheral.UUID];
    [self sendNotification:str];
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be expressing inside this function as a novice Swift developer. Can anyone explain or perhaps provide a practical example? I assume my CBCentralManager needs to referred to at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered nothing is required inside of this function; it simply executes it automatically or so it seems on my end. An NSLog or println() might be advisable.